# Call to undefined relationship [pointage] on model [App\Salarie]?

Tags: mysql, laravel, database-migration

I want to display the POINTAGE, and SALARY table data from ControllerSalarie, but it gives me this error

**Pointage Model**

```
public function salarie()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Salarie');
}
```

**Salarie Model**

```
public function pointages()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Pointage');
}
```

migration migration salarie_id

```
 /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('pointages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('salarie_id')->unsigned()->after('id');
            $table->foreign('salarie_id')->references('id')->on('salaries');  
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('pointages', function (Blueprint $table) {
             $table->dropForeign(['salarie_id']);
            $table->dropCulomn('salarie_id');
        });
    }
```

**SalarieController**

```
public function consulter()
{      
    $salaries=Salarie::with('pointage')->get();
    $pointages = DB::table('pointages')->pluck("pointage","id")->all();
    return view('salarie.consulter', compact('salaries', 'pointages'));
}
```

Comment: Curious, why was my answer accepted and then unaccepted... it's the same answer and it came in over an hour earlier... ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change:

```
$salaries=Salarie::with('pointage')->get();
```

to:

```
$salaries=Salarie::with('pointages')->get();
```

Comment: I am sorry, I know that your answer is the first, but I saw Ahmed's answer and i edit the code, so pay attention to other answers,thx bro :)

Answer (score 3):

Just change `with('pointage')` to `with('pointages')`